# Android ImageButton - How to hide the image while showing the background?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, visibility, imagebutton

I've read the API and Googled but perhaps I've missed something: All the visibility options on an ImageButton seem to talk about this view as a whole. So, what should I do if I want to hide the image but keep the background(except for explicitly setting the image to something transparent that is)? I'm doing a Pairs Game and when one clicks on the element it should show the image and if the next click doesn't match the image should be hidden, but the grey background of the button should remain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, what should I do if I want to hide the image

Try setting it to `@null` or create transparent PNG in your drawables and set it.

Answer (score 2):

in XML, remove `android:src="something"` and in the code remove `imgbtn.setImageBitmap(null);`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ImageButton you can use ImageView with a FrameLayout on top of it. Set the background of FrameLayout as gray color and then show/hide this FrameLayout/Image as per your requirement. Take relative layout for each and make it clickable. On the click event of this layout, do the changes as required.